# How to set state in nested array of objects in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-hooks

I have this object as a state in reactjs. I want to add another object inside the "*childoptions: []*" array which is nested inside the options array on button click.

How can I achieve this, pls help...

```
  const [select1, setSelect1] = useState({
    id: uuid(),
    type: 'select',
    properties: {
      label: 'Select1',
      options: [
        // {
        //   id: uuid(),
        //   optionName: 'red ',
        //   value: '',
        //   childOptions: [],
        // },
        // {
        //   id: uuid(),
        //   optionName: 'green ',
        //   value: '',
        //   childOptions: [],
        // },
        // {
        //   id: uuid(),
        //   optionName: 'blue ',
        //   value: '',
        //   childOptions: [],
        // },
      ],
    },
    parentId: null,
  });
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by copy the `prevState` in the new state with the new object inserted inside the options array.

A more detailed explanation could be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26254086/9095807

```js
setSelect1((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    properties: {
      label: 'Select1',
      options: prevState.properties.options.map(obj => obj.id === id ? { ...obj, childOptions: [...obj.childOptions, newChildOptions] } : obj),
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello @Girgetto, thanks for your answer. I want here to insert an object inside the "childoptions" property of "options" array. this is a more nested object.

Comment: Got it, I've changed the code, to be able to perform it you'll need to know the `id` of the object where you would like to add the `childOptions` array and the `newChildOptions`